# Python- regular expression to print word within link

Tags: python, regex, dictionary, jupyter-notebook

I am using Jupyter Notebook to get docid=PE209374738 as my output using reg ex. It is currently stored in a dictionary in this format: 
`{'Url': 'https://backtoschool.com/document.php?docid=PE209374738&datasource=PHE&vid=3326&referrer=api'}`.

This is my code:

```
results= xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("result")
dict= {}
for a in results:
    url= 'Url'
    dict[url] = a.getElementsByTagName("url")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
    docid= re.search(r'\?(.*?)&')
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to print that id?

Answer (score 3):

The standard library already has methods for parsing URLs properly, no need for regex.

In Python 3:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs

url = 'https://backtoschool.com/document.php?docid=PE209374738&datasource=PHE&vid=3326&referrer=api'
print(parse_qs(urlparse(url).query)['docid'][0])  # PE209374738
```

In Python 2 the first line is:

```
from urlparse import urlparse, parse_qs
```

Answer (score 2):

@alex-hall is correct, you probably should better parse this using a proper URL parser.

That said, your original question was about doing it with using regexps, so here is the solution (which you nearly nailed already):

```
s = 'https://backtoschool.com/document.php?docid=PE209374738&datasource=PHE&vid=3326&referrer=api'
m = re.search(r'\?docid=(.*?)&', s)
print m.groups()[0]
```

This will print the desired `PE209374738`.